# Clear a Lookup Field in an upsert call through Rest API

Tags: rest-api, externalid

We're building an interface to upsert records into a Custom Object through Rest API.
We're building the relationship to other records through external Ids, so we're using the following json structure:

```
{
    "Project__r" : {
        "ExternalSystemId__c" : "1234"
    }
}
```

Now we're looking also for a way to remove those relationships, e.g. setting the Project__c to NULL. Is there a way through the External Id way to empty those fields, or do we need to use the regular external id field e.g.

```
{
   "Project__c" : null
}
```

to do so?

Comment: Did you actually try setting `ExternalSystemId__c` to null to see what happens?

Comment: Yes I already tried this but the API returns an error for it.

Comment: AFAIK, you have to clear the lookup field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now came up with workaround solution to be able to keep the interface logic as is.

We created a dummy record with an externalSystemId__c = 'invalid' and use this every time we need to null the Project relation. We then built a before insert/update flow that checks if this Project is used, and then sets the field to null.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to remove our lookup relationship by sending an empty string.

So for your example.

This:
{
"Project__c" : " "
}

Instead of:
{
"Project__c" : null
}